# What are the minimal privileges required to execute Oracle BulkCopy ?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have trying to run Oracle BulkCopy from DataAccess.Client.
However i'm facing the problem of insufficient privileges.
I have provided SELECT FROM ANY TABLE and INSERT ANY TABLE privileges . 
Are there any other privileges to be added ?